# Side notes in outer margin (»outer column«)

Tags: header-footer, koma-script, two-column, tufte, sidenotes

I have a text with lots of comments. I would like to typeset it in quasi twocolumn fashion, bookstyle -- inner column: text, outer column: comments as sidenotes. Headers and headings above both columns (text and outer margin), pagenumber bottom, centralized. I tried to do it with the `sidenotes` package as well as with the `tufte-latex` in combination with `geometry` and `\geometry`.

I got sidenotes in the outer margins. But they are aligned to the sidenote-numbers paragraphs in text. I would like them to follow one another directly (no additional baseline skips between side notes). Also I was not able to get headers (left, middle, right) above text and outer margin (the two columns), the same with centralized headings. When using `twocolumn` or `multicol` I was not able to get the sidenotes in the outer column. Do you have any suggestions, how to do it?

I tried to do it with `tufte-latex`. It looks quite good, but there are some problems

- If I use the option "justified" it does not work.
- The sectionname ist not centered.
- The `side notes` don't follow one another. They don't start at the first line after the `section`[image: This is still needed!]

  ```
  \documentclass[symmetric,pagestyles]{tufte-book}
  \geometry{outer=10.5cm, inner=2.7cm, heightrounded, marginparwidth=7.3cm, marginparsep=0.45cm}
  \usepackage{lmodern}

  \fancyhf{}
  \fancyhead[RO,LE]{Etiam lobortis} %Kopfzeile rechts
  \fancyhead[C]{Dolor sit amet} %zentrierte Kopfzeile
  \fancyhead[RE,LO]{\nouppercase{\rightmark}} %Kopfzeile rechts
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt} %obere Trennlinie
  \fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}



  \begin{document}

  \section{Lorem ipsum}

  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.\sidenote{Lorem ipsum
  dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.} Etiam lobortis facilisis sem. Nullam
  nec mi et neque pharetra sollicitudin.\sidenote{Etiam lobortis facilisis
  sem. Nullam nec mi et neque pharetra sollicitudin.} Praesent imperdiet mi nec
  ante. Donec ullamcorper, felis non sodales commodo, lectus velit ultrices augue, a
  dignissim nibh lectus placerat pede.\sidenote{Praesent imperdiet mi nec ante. Donec
  ullamcorper, felis non sodales commodo, lectus velit ultrices augue, a dignissim
  nibh lectus placerat pede.} Vivamus nunc nunc, molestie ut, ultricies vel, semper
  in, velit. Ut porttitor.\sidenote{Vivamus nunc nunc, molestie ut, ultricies vel,
  semper in, velit. Ut porttitor.} Praesent in sapien. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
  consectetuer adipiscing elit.\sidenote{Praesent in sapien. Lorem ipsum dolor sit
  amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.}  Duis fringilla tristique neque. Sed interdum
  libero ut metus.  Pellentesque placerat.\sidenote{ Duis fringilla tristique
  neque. Sed interdum libero ut metus.  Pellentesque placerat.} Nam rutrum augue a
  leo. Morbi sed elit sit amet ante lobortis sollicitudin.\sidenote{Nam rutrum augue
  a leo. Morbi sed elit sit amet ante lobortis sollicitudin.} Praesent blandit
  blandit mauris.  Praesent lectus tellus, aliquet aliquam, luctus a, egestas a,
  turpis.\sidenote{Praesent blandit blandit mauris.  Praesent lectus tellus, aliquet
  aliquam, luctus a, egestas a, turpis.} Mauris lacinia lorem sit amet ipsum. Nunc
  quis urna dictum turpis accumsan semper.\sidenote{Mauris lacinia lorem sit amet
  ipsum. Nunc quis urna dictum turpis accumsan semper.}

  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.\sidenote{Lorem ipsum
  dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.} Etiam lobortis facilisis sem. Nullam
  nec mi et neque pharetra sollicitudin.\sidenote{Etiam lobortis facilisis
  sem. Nullam nec mi et neque pharetra sollicitudin.} Praesent imperdiet mi nec
  ante. Donec ullamcorper, felis non sodales commodo, lectus velit ultrices augue, a
  dignissim nibh lectus placerat pede.\sidenote{Praesent imperdiet mi nec ante. Donec
  ullamcorper, felis non sodales commodo, lectus velit ultrices augue, a dignissim
  nibh lectus placerat pede.} Vivamus nunc nunc, molestie ut, ultricies vel, semper
  in, velit. Ut porttitor.\sidenote{Vivamus nunc nunc, molestie ut, ultricies vel,
  semper in, velit. Ut porttitor.} Praesent in sapien. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
  consectetuer adipiscing elit.\sidenote{Praesent in sapien. Lorem ipsum dolor sit
  amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.}  Duis fringilla tristique neque. Sed interdum
  libero ut metus.  Pellentesque placerat.\sidenote{ Duis fringilla tristique
  neque. Sed interdum libero ut metus.  Pellentesque placerat.} Nam rutrum augue a
  leo. Morbi sed elit sit amet ante lobortis sollicitudin.\sidenote{Nam rutrum augue
  a leo. Morbi sed elit sit amet ante lobortis sollicitudin.} Praesent blandit
  blandit mauris.  Praesent lectus tellus, aliquet aliquam, luctus a, egestas a,
  turpis.\sidenote{Praesent blandit blandit mauris.  Praesent lectus tellus, aliquet
  aliquam, luctus a, egestas a, turpis.} Mauris lacinia lorem sit amet ipsum. Nunc
  quis urna dictum turpis accumsan semper.\sidenote{Mauris lacinia lorem sit amet
  ipsum. Nunc quis urna dictum turpis accumsan semper.}

  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.\sidenote{Lorem ipsum
  dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.} Etiam lobortis facilisis sem. Nullam
  nec mi et neque pharetra sollicitudin.\sidenote{Etiam lobortis facilisis
  sem. Nullam nec mi et neque pharetra sollicitudin.} Praesent imperdiet mi nec
  ante. Donec ullamcorper, felis non sodales commodo, lectus velit ultrices augue, a
  dignissim nibh lectus placerat pede.\sidenote{Praesent imperdiet mi nec ante. Donec
  ullamcorper, felis non sodales commodo, lectus velit ultrices augue, a dignissim
  nibh lectus placerat pede.} Vivamus nunc nunc, molestie ut, ultricies vel, semper
  in, velit. Ut porttitor.\sidenote{Vivamus nunc nunc, molestie ut, ultricies vel,
  semper in, velit. Ut porttitor.} Praesent in sapien. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
  consectetuer adipiscing elit.\sidenote{Praesent in sapien. Lorem ipsum dolor sit
  amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.}  Duis fringilla tristique neque. Sed interdum
  libero ut metus.  Pellentesque placerat.\sidenote{ Duis fringilla tristique
  neque. Sed interdum libero ut metus.  Pellentesque placerat.} Nam rutrum augue a
  leo. Morbi sed elit sit amet ante lobortis sollicitudin.\sidenote{Nam rutrum augue
  a leo. Morbi sed elit sit amet ante lobortis sollicitudin.} Praesent blandit
  blandit mauris.  Praesent lectus tellus, aliquet aliquam, luctus a, egestas a,
  turpis.\sidenote{Praesent blandit blandit mauris.  Praesent lectus tellus, aliquet
  aliquam, luctus a, egestas a, turpis.} Mauris lacinia lorem sit amet ipsum. Nunc
  quis urna dictum turpis accumsan semper.\sidenote{Mauris lacinia lorem sit amet
  ipsum. Nunc quis urna dictum turpis accumsan semper.}

  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.\sidenote{Lorem ipsum
  dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.} Etiam lobortis facilisis sem. Nullam
  nec mi et neque pharetra sollicitudin.\sidenote{Etiam lobortis facilisis
  sem. Nullam nec mi et neque pharetra sollicitudin.} Praesent imperdiet mi nec
  ante. Donec ullamcorper, felis non sodales commodo, lectus velit ultrices augue, a
  dignissim nibh lectus placerat pede.\sidenote{Praesent imperdiet mi nec ante. Donec
  ullamcorper, felis non sodales commodo, lectus velit ultrices augue, a dignissim
  nibh lectus placerat pede.} Vivamus nunc nunc, molestie ut, ultricies vel, semper
  in, velit. Ut porttitor.\sidenote{Vivamus nunc nunc, molestie ut, ultricies vel,
  semper in, velit. Ut porttitor.} Praesent in sapien. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
  consectetuer adipiscing elit.\sidenote{Praesent in sapien. Lorem ipsum dolor sit
  amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.}  Duis fringilla tristique neque. Sed interdum
  libero ut metus.  Pellentesque placerat.\sidenote{ Duis fringilla tristique
  neque. Sed interdum libero ut metus.  Pellentesque placerat.} Nam rutrum augue a
  leo. Morbi sed elit sit amet ante lobortis sollicitudin.\sidenote{Nam rutrum augue
  a leo. Morbi sed elit sit amet ante lobortis sollicitudin.} Praesent blandit
  blandit mauris.  Praesent lectus tellus, aliquet aliquam, luctus a, egestas a,
  turpis.\sidenote{Praesent blandit blandit mauris.  Praesent lectus tellus, aliquet
  aliquam, luctus a, egestas a, turpis.} Mauris lacinia lorem sit amet ipsum. Nunc
  quis urna dictum turpis accumsan semper.\sidenote{Mauris lacinia lorem sit amet
  ipsum. Nunc quis urna dictum turpis accumsan semper.}

  \end{document}
  ```

[image: This is what I have in mind, of course, if I could have done it with LaTeX, it would look much nicer …]

Comment: Add your *.tex file you made for this printout. Do you really whish to start a new sidenote in the outer column in the middle of a line? If your annotation are important, why make them so difficult to find while reading the main text?

Comment: Dear Keks Dose, thank you for your reaction. It is exactly my problem, that I am not able to do this in LaTeX. // If I had three or four sidenotes attended to the last paragraf, they would go out of the page-space. I would to have to fix it manualy quite on every page, pushing them upwards. In the way I thought of, I would have only problems on two or three pages within the whole document. (And: I need the optical feeling of two columns.)

Comment: Just to make it clear: I would like to have something like in the pic.

Answer (score 1):

To my understanding the main issue is the sync between main text and the sidenote. The number of the sidenote in the main text and the text of the sidenote should be on the same page, but if the sidenote is too long for the page, it should be continued on the next page.

I have no idea, how to start a new sidenote in the same line, in which the last sidenote has its end.

That said, I suggest to use KOMA-script, mainly the scrlayer packages. My solution isn't perfect, especially I have difficulties with the `\hangfrom`, the hanging box with the number of the sidenote. But see yourself:

```
\documentclass[twoside=true, parskip=half]{scrbook} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage, scrlayer-notecolumn,
lmodern, blindtext, ragged2e, microtype, calc}

\areaset[-2cm]{9cm}{23cm}

\usepackage[latin]{babel}

%% step 1: counter 
\newcounter{snmark} \setcounter{snmark}{0}


%% step 2: hanging sidenotes, definition from tugboat 
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\hangfrom}[1]{% 
\setbox\@tempboxa\hbox{{#1}}% 
\hangindent\wd\@tempboxa
  \noindent\box\@tempboxa} 
\makeatletter

%% step 3: define sidenote marks in the text 
\newcommand{\makesidenotemark}{%
\textsuperscript{\thesnmark} }%


%% step 4: and now the definition of sidenotes 
\newcommand{\sidenote}[1]{%
\refstepcounter{snmark}% Zähler erhöhen 
\makesidenotemark{}% Nummer im Text setzen.
\makenote[paragraphs]{% 
\protect\hangfrom{% 
\protect\makebox[0.5em][l]{%
\thesnmark} } \protect\RaggedRight{} #1}% Text setzen im Rand 
}




\newlength{\notescolwidth} \setlength{\notescolwidth}{8cm}


\DeclareNewNoteColumn[% marginpar, 
width = \notescolwidth, font=\footnotesize,
]{paragraphs}

%\recalctypearea

\title{Sidenotes}

%% Delete all sidenotes: %\renewcommand{\sidenote}[1]{\relax}

\begin{document}
\maketitle{}

  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.\sidenote{Lorem ipsum
dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.} Etiam lobortis facilisis sem. Nullam
nec mi et neque pharetra sollicitudin.\sidenote{Etiam lobortis facilisis
sem. Nullam nec mi et neque pharetra sollicitudin.} Praesent imperdiet mi nec
ante. Donec ullamcorper, felis non sodales commodo, lectus velit ultrices augue, a
dignissim nibh lectus placerat pede.\sidenote{Praesent imperdiet mi nec ante. Donec
ullamcorper, felis non sodales commodo, lectus velit ultrices augue, a dignissim
nibh lectus placerat pede.} Vivamus nunc nunc, molestie ut, ultricies vel, semper
in, velit. Ut porttitor.\sidenote{Vivamus nunc nunc, molestie ut, ultricies vel,
semper in, velit. Ut porttitor.} Praesent in sapien. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
consectetuer adipiscing elit.\sidenote{Praesent in sapien. Lorem ipsum dolor sit
amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.}  Duis fringilla tristique neque. Sed interdum
libero ut metus.  Pellentesque placerat.\sidenote{ Duis fringilla tristique
neque. Sed interdum libero ut metus.  Pellentesque placerat.} Nam rutrum augue a
leo. Morbi sed elit sit amet ante lobortis sollicitudin.\sidenote{Nam rutrum augue
a leo. Morbi sed elit sit amet ante lobortis sollicitudin.} Praesent blandit
blandit mauris.  Praesent lectus tellus, aliquet aliquam, luctus a, egestas a,
turpis.\sidenote{Praesent blandit blandit mauris.  Praesent lectus tellus, aliquet
aliquam, luctus a, egestas a, turpis.} Mauris lacinia lorem sit amet ipsum. Nunc
quis urna dictum turpis accumsan semper.\sidenote{Mauris lacinia lorem sit amet
ipsum. Nunc quis urna dictum turpis accumsan semper.}

  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.\sidenote{Lorem ipsum
dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.} Etiam lobortis facilisis sem. Nullam
nec mi et neque pharetra sollicitudin.\sidenote{Etiam lobortis facilisis
sem. Nullam nec mi et neque pharetra sollicitudin.} Praesent imperdiet mi nec
ante. Donec ullamcorper, felis non sodales commodo, lectus velit ultrices augue, a
dignissim nibh lectus placerat pede.\sidenote{Praesent imperdiet mi nec ante. Donec
ullamcorper, felis non sodales commodo, lectus velit ultrices augue, a dignissim
nibh lectus placerat pede.} Vivamus nunc nunc, molestie ut, ultricies vel, semper
in, velit. Ut porttitor.\sidenote{Vivamus nunc nunc, molestie ut, ultricies vel,
semper in, velit. Ut porttitor.} Praesent in sapien. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
consectetuer adipiscing elit.\sidenote{Praesent in sapien. Lorem ipsum dolor sit
amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.}  Duis fringilla tristique neque. Sed interdum
libero ut metus.  Pellentesque placerat.\sidenote{ Duis fringilla tristique
neque. Sed interdum libero ut metus.  Pellentesque placerat.} Nam rutrum augue a
leo. Morbi sed elit sit amet ante lobortis sollicitudin.\sidenote{Nam rutrum augue
a leo. Morbi sed elit sit amet ante lobortis sollicitudin.} Praesent blandit
blandit mauris.  Praesent lectus tellus, aliquet aliquam, luctus a, egestas a,
turpis.\sidenote{Praesent blandit blandit mauris.  Praesent lectus tellus, aliquet
aliquam, luctus a, egestas a, turpis.} Mauris lacinia lorem sit amet ipsum. Nunc
quis urna dictum turpis accumsan semper.\sidenote{Mauris lacinia lorem sit amet
ipsum. Nunc quis urna dictum turpis accumsan semper.}

  \syncwithnotecolumns[paragraphs]

 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.\sidenote{Lorem ipsum
dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.} Etiam lobortis facilisis sem. Nullam
nec mi et neque pharetra sollicitudin.\sidenote{Etiam lobortis facilisis
sem. Nullam nec mi et neque pharetra sollicitudin.} Praesent imperdiet mi nec
ante. Donec ullamcorper, felis non sodales commodo, lectus velit ultrices augue, a
dignissim nibh lectus placerat pede.\sidenote{Praesent imperdiet mi nec ante. Donec
ullamcorper, felis non sodales commodo, lectus velit ultrices augue, a dignissim
nibh lectus placerat pede.} Vivamus nunc nunc, molestie ut, ultricies vel, semper
in, velit. Ut porttitor.\sidenote{Vivamus nunc nunc, molestie ut, ultricies vel,
semper in, velit. Ut porttitor.} Praesent in sapien. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
consectetuer adipiscing elit.\sidenote{Praesent in sapien. Lorem ipsum dolor sit
amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.}  Duis fringilla tristique neque. Sed interdum
libero ut metus.  Pellentesque placerat.\sidenote{ Duis fringilla tristique
neque. Sed interdum libero ut metus.  Pellentesque placerat.} Nam rutrum augue a
leo. Morbi sed elit sit amet ante lobortis sollicitudin.\sidenote{Nam rutrum augue
a leo. Morbi sed elit sit amet ante lobortis sollicitudin.} Praesent blandit
blandit mauris.  Praesent lectus tellus, aliquet aliquam, luctus a, egestas a,
turpis.\sidenote{Praesent blandit blandit mauris.  Praesent lectus tellus, aliquet
aliquam, luctus a, egestas a, turpis.} Mauris lacinia lorem sit amet ipsum. Nunc
quis urna dictum turpis accumsan semper.\sidenote{Mauris lacinia lorem sit amet
ipsum. Nunc quis urna dictum turpis accumsan semper.}




  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.\sidenote{Lorem ipsum
dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.} Etiam lobortis facilisis sem. Nullam
nec mi et neque pharetra sollicitudin.\sidenote{Etiam lobortis facilisis
sem. Nullam nec mi et neque pharetra sollicitudin.} Praesent imperdiet mi nec
ante. Donec ullamcorper, felis non sodales commodo, lectus velit ultrices augue, a
dignissim nibh lectus placerat pede.\sidenote{Praesent imperdiet mi nec ante. Donec
ullamcorper, felis non sodales commodo, lectus velit ultrices augue, a dignissim
nibh lectus placerat pede.} Vivamus nunc nunc, molestie ut, ultricies vel, semper
in, velit. Ut porttitor.\sidenote{Vivamus nunc nunc, molestie ut, ultricies vel,
semper in, velit. Ut porttitor.} Praesent in sapien. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
consectetuer adipiscing elit.\sidenote{Praesent in sapien. Lorem ipsum dolor sit
amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.}  Duis fringilla tristique neque. Sed interdum
libero ut metus.  Pellentesque placerat.\sidenote{ Duis fringilla tristique
neque. Sed interdum libero ut metus.  Pellentesque placerat.} Nam rutrum augue a
leo. Morbi sed elit sit amet ante lobortis sollicitudin.\sidenote{Nam rutrum augue
a leo. Morbi sed elit sit amet ante lobortis sollicitudin.} Praesent blandit
blandit mauris.  Praesent lectus tellus, aliquet aliquam, luctus a, egestas a,
turpis.\sidenote{Praesent blandit blandit mauris.  Praesent lectus tellus, aliquet
aliquam, luctus a, egestas a, turpis.} Mauris lacinia lorem sit amet ipsum. Nunc
quis urna dictum turpis accumsan semper.\sidenote{Mauris lacinia lorem sit amet
ipsum. Nunc quis urna dictum turpis accumsan semper.}


\end{document}
```

I just show the pagebreak, you can see one sidenotes goes on on the next page:

[image: Page break with running marginnotes]

Comment: Thank you for the answer Keks Dose. But thougt it slightly different. I tried it using tufte. It already looks good, but if I use the option "justified", it does not work.

Comment: I edited my question, putting in some code and a new pic. Maybe it will be usefull for solving the problem and making clear what I want.